# Gradle: What is the counterpart to ant's buildnumber

Tags: build, gradle

I've been trying to migrate an ant script to gradle and have so far not found gradle's counterpart to the ant `<buildnumber/>` which is an auto-incrementing number used within the build process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gradle doesn't have a counterpart to `<buildnumber/>`, but you can always use the Ant task.

Answer (score 4):

In case there are any other noobs out there like me that don't know how to execute ant targets and access their properties, here's an example:

```groovy
jar.doFirst {
  ant.buildnumber()
  manifest {
    attributes{
      'Implementation-Version': ant.antProject.properties['build.number']
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution as it requires nothing else - no more imports, files or plugins